# How can I include group method when using group collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are 4 models.(Fashion,FashionUnderwear,Underwear,Brand).Each user can select his own style from the fashion form.The fashion form has various item's drop boxes such as jeans and socks.I wanted to rearrange the items classified by brand in the Drop box alphabetically, so I used the scope.

```
#### Underwear dropbox
Adidas
  adidas underwear 1
  adidas underwear 2
NIKE
  NIKE underwear 1
  NIKE underwear 2
  NIKE underwear 3
```

It worked well with the scope, but now I got a warning that you should include the scope.
In the code below, opening Fashions/new.html will give me a warning "Please Include UnderwearNameAsc".
I studied various things and tried it, but in all cases using child models, I can not find a clue to solve.

```
### Fashion model
has_one :fashion_underwear
accepts_nested_attributes_for :fashion_underwear

### FashionUnderwear model(Intermediate table)
belongs_to :fashion
belongs_to :underwear

### Underwear model
has_many :fashion_underwears
belongs_to :brand

scope :UnderwearNameAsc, -> { order(UnderwearName: :asc) }

### Brand model
has_many :underwear

has_many :UnderwearNameAsc, -> { order(UnderwearName: :asc) }, class_name: 'Underwear'

### Fashions.controller
def new
  @fashion = Fashion.new
  @fashion.build_fashion_underwear
  @brand = Brand.includes(:fashion_underwears).joins(:fashion_underwears).order(brand_name: :asc)
end

### Fashion/new.html
= simple_form_for(@fashion) do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :fashion_underwear do |p|
    = p.input :underwear_id, collection: @brand, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :UnderwearNameAsc, group_label_method: :brand_name, label_method: :UnderwearName
```

Comment: You are getting a warning from where? Please show the server logs.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Gem Bullet said, USE eager loading detected Brand => [: UnderwearNameAsc] Add to your finder:: includes => [: UnderwearNameAsc].

Answer (score 0):

Bullet is pointing out that you have an [n+1 query problem](https://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/). It suggests that you change your has_many association within the Brand model by adding an `includes` to solve the problem, like this:

```
has_many :UnderwearNameAsc, -> { includes(:underwear).order(UnderwearName: :asc) }, class_name: 'Underwear'
```

While you are at it, you really should change the names of your scopes and methods to snake_case in [standard Ruby style](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars). Otherwise Ruby will think those methods and scopes are constants.

Also, I would just name your scope for what it is returning, not for a single attribute on that model. Finally, I'd use a scope separately and call it explicitly when you want the resources to be returned sorted.

```
has_many :underwear # Or has_many :underwears if Rails interprets the plural that way
scope :sorted, -> { includes(:underwear).order(underwear: {name: :asc} }
```

Then you can do:

```
Brand.all # Returns unsorted records
Brand.all.sorted # Returns records sorted by underwear.name
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  I practiced what you taught me, but an error has appeared. I tried to solve it myself, but I could not do it.  The error says that Association named 'underwear' was not found on Underwear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support!